# knockout mapping json via Ajax call

Tags: knockout-mapping-plugin

I try to map and bind JSON data directly in an Ajax call without success. The alert shows the requested data. If I copy/paste the content of this alert into a test variable, then the mapping works fine. Why can't I map/bind directly to the result? What could be the difference between 'test' and 'result.d'? (binding to result - without .d doesn't work either).

Thanks for any help.

```
 var test = { "formulier": { "titel": "test", "formulier_id": 4, "vragen": [{ "vraag_id": 5, "vraag": "Hoe gaat het?", "soortvraag_id": 4, "soortwaarde_id": 13, "verplicht": false, "antwoorden": [] }, { "vraag_id": 6, "vraag": "Dit is een kopje", "soortvraag_id": 18, "soortwaarde_id": 13, "verplicht": false, "antwoorden": [] }, { "vraag_id": 3, "vraag": "vraag 3k", "soortvraag_id": 6, "soortwaarde_id": 13, "verplicht": false, "antwoorden": [{ "antwoord": "nieuw2", "antwoord_id": 7, "vraag_id": 3, "iscorrect": true }, { "antwoord": "echt waar?", "antwoord_id": 5, "vraag_id": 3, "iscorrect": false }, { "antwoord": "nieuw 123", "antwoord_id": 2, "vraag_id": 3, "iscorrect": false }, { "antwoord": "nieuw", "antwoord_id": 6, "vraag_id": 3, "iscorrect": false }] }] } }

            // This doesn't work 
            $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        url: "../formulierService.asmx/getLeegFormulier",
                        data: "{'id': " + 4 + "}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result.d); //content of alert was pasted into var test above
                            var ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.d); 
                            ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
                        }
            });

            // This does work
            var ViewModel2 = ko.mapping.fromJS(test);
            ko.applyBindings(ViewModel2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, to use fromJS , you need to deserialise your json string to a js object.

`var test = JSON.parse(result.d);`

then, call

`var ViewModel2 = ko.mapping.fromJS(test);`

Another option is to directly use `fromJSON`, instead of `fromJS`:

`var ViewModel2 = ko.mapping.fromJSON(result.d);`